# Line being added to top of each page of PDF

Tags: pdf

I have just noticed that a line is being added to the top of all PDF pages. I am using TcpdfFpdi v2 from setasign and everything else seems to work as expected (bringing in Pdf pages, adding a logo and text)

Code as follows…

```
use setasign\Fpdi\TcpdfFpdi;
```

```
public  function test($uuid, $date)
{
        $pdf = new TcpdfFpdi();
        $pdf->output('test.pdf', 'D');
}
```

I would expect this to give me a blank page but it is giving me a page with a line across the top (about 1cm down and in from each side).

Answer (score 4):

Setasign tech support have answered this for me…

> This is the default behavior of TCPDF (why ever) and you need to explicitly disable the default header and/or footer:

```
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
```